# http://domain.com is not opening in a wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

http://domain.com is not opening in a wordpress site. When I type domain.com in webbrowser, it is automatically going to www.domain.com. But when I type http://domain.com it says 'This site can’t be reached".. how can i solve this issue please let me know ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use following line in Apache server httpd.conf file.

```
<VirtualHost *>
  DocumentRoot /var/www
  ServerName www.domain.com
  ServerAlias domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Then restart the server.

```
service httpd reload
```

or

```
service apache2 restart
```